# Background image size on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My background image seems to not display on mobile devices. It looks fine on desktop browsers scaled to mobile size but when loaded on Safari on my iPhone it doesn't appear. The link is: http://lamda.jwoods.me/ . I have included the relevant HTML and CSS and an image of how it appears on my phone for reference.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron main-jumbo">
  <nav class="navbar transparent navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Drama Centre</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="lamda.html">About LAMDA</a></li>
          <li><a href="benefits.html">Benefits</a></li>
          <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
          <li><a href="teachers.html">Teachers</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-sm hidden-xs">
          <li class="visible-lg-block"><a class="navtext">Follow us: </a></li>
          <li><a href="#fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#ig"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container jumbo-container">
        <h1> The Drama Centre </h1>

        <h4> A leading LAMDA specific centre in Wiltshire </h4>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-jumbo {
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)
    ),
  url("../img/jumbobgweb.jpg");

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  min-height: 60

.main-jumbo h1, .main-jumbo h4{
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}


.jumbo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Mobile image:

[image: Mobile image]

Comment: Not duplicate, updated to code to that and still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line of CSS fixed my issue:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .main-jumbo {
      background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
```

Apparently background-attachment: scroll works much better on mobile than fixed.